# Tikz node text vertical align with linebreak

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, nodes

I want to vertical align text in a chain of nodes. One node has a linebreak. What is the best way to do this? This is my current example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        start chain,
        every node/.style={
            draw,
            text height=1.5ex,
            text depth=.0ex,
            text width=7em,
            text centered,
            anchor=base,
            minimum height=3em
        }]

        \node[on chain, join] {node with\\linebreak};
        \node[on chain, join] {node};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want my first node to be vertically aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

The code of above image is:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      start chain = going right,
every node/.style = {
    draw,
    minimum height=3em,
    text width=7em,
    align=center,
    on chain, join}
            ]
        \node  {node with\\linebreak};
        \node  {node};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I only change parameters of your `every node/.style ...`. If you define text height and depth, than TikZ use text height for the first line of text and other lines put below it. So better is to declare `minimum height=...`. New syntax for text centering is `align=center`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `minipage` to allow the line break within the node.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        start chain,
        every node/.style={
            draw,
            text height=1.5ex,
            text depth=.0ex,
            text width=7em,
            text centered,
            anchor=base,
            minimum height=3em
        }]

        \node[on chain, join] {\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\centering
        node with \\ linebreak
        \end{minipage}};
        \node[on chain, join] {node};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```